# Extract data from webpage with Python

Tags: python

For training purposes ,i'am trying to extract the line :

```
<td>2017/01/15</td>
```

from the following webpage (inspect element preview) :

```
   <div class="bodyy">
            <div id="FullPart">
                                <p class="d_intro">


                <table id="ldeface" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td class="dtime">Date</td>
                        <td class="datt">Notifier</td>
                        <td class="dHMR">H</td>
                        <td class="dHMR">M</td>
                        <td class="dHMR">R</td>
                        <td class="dhMR">L</td>
                        <td class="dR"><img src="/images/star.gif" border="0"></td>
                        <td class="dDom">Domain</td>
                        <td class="dos">OS</td>
                        <td class="dview">View</td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>2017/02/10</td>
                        <td><a href="/testarchive/</a></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
```

I'am confused how will i get the td parts and which parts are correct (class/id) in order to fetch the correct information with BeatifulSoup.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try [scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/) and read their docs

Answer (score 2):

For your example you should use next thing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('yor_html_source', 'html.parser')
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
     tr = table.findAll('tr')[1]
     td = tr.findAll('td')[0].text
print(td) # return 2017/02/10
```

If you want get just `<td>2017/02/10</td>` remove `text` property from `td` variable.

BeautifulSoup4 have also cool [Soup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 1):

**Gather The Data:**

To get the data to process you can use [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib2
resource = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.somewebsite.com/somepage")
html = resource.read()
# assuming html is the example with a few more rows in the table
```

**Process the Data:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
for table in soup.findAll("table"):
    if table.attrs['id'] == 'ldeface':
        rows = table.findAll("tr")
        header = rows[0]
        date_col = [ i for i, col in enumerate(header.findAll("td")) if col.text == "Date"][0]
        for row in rows[1:]:
            print row.findAll("td")[date_col].text
```

**Result:**

```
2017/02/10
2017/02/11
2017/03/10
...
```

You can extract other columns based on the text in the cell, the id attribute like I did for the table, or the class attribute in a similar way to the table

Comment: There's urllib3 now, I'll post my own answer for the newer code. This answer got me headed in the right direction though :-) +1

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags=[str(tag) for tag in soup.find_all()]
for elem in tags:
   if '<td>' in elem and len(elem.split('/')==4):
       print(elem.text)
```

Go through all the tags, if the tag is a td and has the right amount of slashes, print it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) via pip:

```
python3 -m pip install urllib3
python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

After that the python code should look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
page = http.request("GET","http://HOST.TLD/CONTENT")
if page.status == 200:
  html = page.data
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
  h1 = soup.find('h1') # we are interested only in the 1st
  print("H1: %s" % (h1))
```